# Magento 2 - Access uiComponent form data in javascript

Tags: javascript, magento, magento2, uicomponents

I'm trying to create a button on my admin form that triggers a confirmation popup then redirects to a custom controller with the id of the current loaded entity in the form. From what I have read in the devdocs, it seems possible to get access to the form data inside a javascript component.

What do I need to require in my component to get access to that data, and how do I access it ?

EDIT

Basically, I'm trying to follow this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_data_source.html but can't find a way to make it work.